# How to make selenium run on a jenkins machine hosted on a linux sever with GUI capabilities?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am looking at ways where I can move my selenium code into a Linux server and integrate it with Jenkins. But facing a challenge as this framework has been designed to capture the screenshots, video record the flow, etc. This might not work in Linux as it's a CLI.

What is the possible solution that I can look for? Will the selenium grid be of any help here?

Comment: As per i know, we need to run the selenium script in head-less mode in Linux through Jenkins. It will capture the screen shot but i am not sure about recording as i never tried.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I've seen something similar working on Zalenium. Check it out, it might be a fit for your request.